# Batch process in firebase to delete data stored for a month

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with an AngularFire application and the data I store in fireBase has a creation date. I want to erased all the data that has been stored from a month up to today's date. Example if "x" object was store on April 9th and Today is May 9th, it should be deleted automatically, so according to the documentation you can have [Transactions and Batched Writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Is it possible to accomplish what I want? or I will have to write a code on the Angular side and every time someone opens the app will check the date and erase what has been stored for a month. I know for Oracle databases this can be accomplished with a batch script, so I was thinking if for FireBase could be done too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible if you're storing the dates in Firebase. There are a few ways to do it, but no matter what you choose, I'd recommend you do it *outside of the client*. It's not a good idea to delete what is potentially a lot of data client-side. You can set up a cron job from a server you control. You run the job periodically and use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to access and delete the data.

You'd have some query that targets the documents, like this example:

```
let query = ref.collection('collectionname').where('timestamp', '<', {variable with the time frame goes here})
```

Then you can use a batch delete, as shown in the [delete data section of the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data).

```
function deleteCollection(db, collectionPath, batchSize) {
  var collectionRef = db.collection(collectionPath);
  var query = collectionRef.where('timestamp', '<', {variable with the time frame goes here});

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
  });
}

function deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject) {
  query.get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        // When there are no documents left, we are done
        if (snapshot.size == 0) {
          return 0;
        }

        // Delete documents in a batch
        var batch = db.batch();
        snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
          batch.delete(doc.ref);
        });

        return batch.commit().then(() => {
          return snapshot.size;
        });
      }).then((numDeleted) => {
        if (numDeleted === 0) {
          resolve();
          return;
        }

        // Recurse on the next process tick, to avoid
        // exploding the stack.
        process.nextTick(() => {
          deleteQueryBatch(db, query, batchSize, resolve, reject);
        });
      })
      .catch(reject);
}
```

This is just a general example so you'll have to customize it to your data structure and needs, but it outlines the idea. You can check out more info in the link I included above.

Comment: wow! I thought it wasn't possible and the word "cron" was exactly a word I was missing (forgot how to say it in english lol) the only question that I have before I take a look to the documentation is the following: you said storing the dates in firebase... I have them inside of each object inside of the firebase 
collection

`{
    "name":"John",
    "age":30,
    "cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ],
    "creationDate" : "05/09/2018"
}` is that okay? or you meant to store it in a different way?

Comment: How are you formatting your date? If it's a string, then it won't order by date but by the string itself, which won't give you the result you want. I'm pretty sure you can still make a string work as long as you're doing YYYY/MM/DD.

Comment: It's a new project with 3 objects in there right now. If you think it will be better to store it as a date then i will do so