# Firebase Auth: Delete all users created on a certain date

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to write a cloud function to delete all user accounts created on May 16 but it's not working.
Am I doing something wrong? It's very hard to debug since I can only test it when I deploy it.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

const listAllUsers = (nextPageToken) => {
    var allUsers = [];
    // List batch of users, 1000 at a time.
    admin
        .auth()
        .listUsers(1000, nextPageToken)
        .then((listUsersResult) => {
            listUsersResult.users.forEach((userRecord) => {
                if (userRecord.metadata.creationTime.includes("May 16")) {
                    allUsers.push(userRecord.uid);
                }

            });
            admin
            .auth()
            .deleteUsers(allUsers)
            .then((deleteUsersResult) => {
                console.log(`Successfully deleted ${deleteUsersResult.successCount} users`);
                console.log(`Failed to delete ${deleteUsersResult.failureCount} users`);
                deleteUsersResult.errors.forEach((err) => {
                    console.log(err.error.toJSON());
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error deleting users:', error);
            });
            if (listUsersResult.pageToken) {
                // List next batch of users.
                listAllUsers(listUsersResult.pageToken);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error listing users:', error);
        });
};
// Start listing users from the beginning, 1000 at a time.

exports.clean = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    listAllUsers();
});
```

I think the problem may be related to this line, but how do I debug this?
`userRecord.metadata.creationTime.includes("May 16")`

This is the console output I get on firebase when I run the function:

```
2:01:38.621 PM
clean
Function execution took 60002 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'
2:00:40.267 PM
clean
Failed to delete 0 users
2:00:40.267 PM
clean
Successfully deleted 0 users
2:00:40.082 PM
clean
Failed to delete 0 users
2:00:40.081 PM
clean
Successfully deleted 0 users
2:00:39.852 PM
clean
Failed to delete 0 users
2:00:39.852 PM
clean
Successfully deleted 0 users
2:00:39.604 PM
clean
Failed to delete 0 users
2:00:39.604 PM
clean
Successfully deleted 0 users
2:00:38.620 PM
clean
Function execution started
12:48:53.792 PM
clean
```

Comment: Does it throw any error? Or It is not doing the intended work?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara thanks for the reply, I added the firebase console output to the question. It's not working as intended

Comment: I think this is because of the timeout, Why don't you try to use batches to delete the users - you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257541/batch-process-in-firebase-to-delete-data-stored-for-a-month) link. It is not the same, but little tweaks might work for you.

Comment: As per the documentation, the [creationTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserMetadata#creationtime) property is formatted as a UTC string. For example, `Sat, 03 Feb 2001 04:05:06 GMT`.
Try using the property's format in your code to see if it works. For instance `userRecord.metadata.creationTime.includes("16 May 2021")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my comment above was helpful, so I'll put it as the answer for better visibility.

The [creationTime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserMetadata#creationtime) property is formatted as a UTC string. For example, `Sat, 03 Feb 2001 04:05:06 GMT`. Use the property's format in your code to make it work, e. g.

`userRecord.metadata.creationTime.includes("16 May 2021")`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I just had the time format wrong. I changed `"May 16"` to `"16 May"` and it worked. And since the function doesn't return a response, I increased the timeout value via the google cloud console to let it finish looping through all the users.